# Django: list comprehension with Q objects

Tags: python, django

As far as I know you can create a list of your filters and then just unpack the list inside the filter() or exclude() methods. Looks super convenient.

I tried to do just that:

```
words_to_exclude = ['one', 'two', 'three']
excluded_clauses = [Q(title__icontains=word) for word in words_to_exclude]
search_result = MyObject.objects.exclude(*excluded_clauses)
```

The query works, but there is one problem. If I create a filter list using this method, this list (excluded_clauses) will look like this:

```
[<Q: (AND: ('title__icontains', 'one'))>, <Q: (AND: ('title__icontains', 'two'))>, <Q: (AND: ('title__icontains', 'three'))>]
```

These are Q objects with AND operator, so the queryset will only exclude objects which do not contain all of the words. And I need it to exclude results where the title includes ANY of the words, so I need the OR operator. Can I manually change the operator in Q objects? Or is there no way to use list comprehension like this?
I'm sorry, I know how to write filters manually, but I need this for a filter function with unspecified number of arguments.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `OR` as connector:

```
words_to_exclude = ['one', 'two', 'three']
excluded_clauses = [Q(title__icontains=word) for word in words_to_exclude]
search_result = MyObject.objects.exclude(*excluded_clauses, _connector=Q.OR)
```

Comment: Nice! Where's `_connector` documented?

Comment: @AKX: it is essentially the same interface as a `Q` object itself (`.filter(..)` and `.exclude(..)`), I think I once found in the documentation the `_connector` parameter, but at the current time can not find it back, but it is the parameter of the `Q.__init__`.

Comment: Looks suggested only for internal usage.: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32946#comment:1

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`operator.or_`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/operator.html#operator.or_) (or equivalently `lambda a, b: a | b` to generate a Q object out of or-joined components:

```
import operator
import functools

words_to_exclude = ["one", "two", "three"]

q = functools.reduce(
    operator.or_,
    (Q(title__icontains=word) for word in words_to_exclude),
)
search_result = MyObject.objects.exclude(q)
```